# Java game - mixing up MousePressed and MouseClicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouselistener, inventory

I've currently trying to set my up my own java game without using any additional libraries to challenge myself. Right now im programming the inventory system for my RPG.

My goal is to be able to click on the item in the inventory and click on the target spot (2x MouseClicked) as well as drag the item from one inventory slot to the other (1x MousePressed, 1x MouseReleased). Events are called by the methods implemented by MouseListener interface on a JFrame.

If I implement one without the other it works fine but if I use both code snippets the MousePressed function seems to interfere when i want to drop the item with MouseClicked.

Heres my code:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(bag.isItemGrabbed())
        {
            bag.deployItem();
        }

        else if(!(bag.isItemGrabbed()))
        {
            bag.grabItem();
        }
    }

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(!(bag.isItemGrabbed()))
    {
        bag.grabItem();
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(bag.isItemGrabbed())
    {
        bag.deployItem();
    }
}
```

grabItem method:

```
public void grabItem()
{
    if(inventoryHover>=0)
    {
        grabbedItem = inventorySlots[inventoryHover];
        grabbedItemQuantity = inventorySlotQuantities[inventoryHover];
        grabbedItemPreviousSlot = inventoryHover;
        inventorySlots[inventoryHover] = null;
        inventorySlotQuantities[inventoryHover] = 0;
    }
}
```

itemDeploy method:

```
public void deployItem()
{
    if(isItemGrabbed()&&inventoryHover>=0)
    {
        if(inventorySlots[inventoryHover]!=null)
        {
                inventorySlots[grabbedItemPreviousSlot]=inventorySlots[inventoryHover];
                inventorySlotQuantities[grabbedItemPreviousSlot]=inventorySlotQuantities[inventoryHover];
                inventorySlots[inventoryHover]=grabbedItem;
                inventorySlotQuantities[inventoryHover]=inventorySlotQuantities[grabbedItemQuantity];
                grabbedItem=null;
                grabbedItemQuantity = 0;
                grabbedItemPreviousSlot = -1;
        }
        else
        {
                inventorySlots[inventoryHover]=grabbedItem;
                inventorySlotQuantities[inventoryHover]=inventorySlotQuantities[grabbedItemQuantity];
                grabbedItem=null;
                grabbedItemQuantity = 0;
                grabbedItemPreviousSlot = -1;
        }
    }
    else if(isItemGrabbed()&&inventoryHover==-1)
    {
            grabbedItem=null;
            grabbedItemQuantity = 0;
            grabbedItemPreviousSlot = -1;
    }
}
```

As I said: If use both Pressed and Clicked i can use the drag&drop function just fine but if I want to do two single clicks the item won't be dropped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for a mouse click you will always get a mouse pressed and mouse released event beforehand. You might want to use MouseMotionListener for your dragging event

Comment: `MouseClicked` will only be called when the mouse hasn't moved from the point it was pressed when released

Comment: I tried using MouseMotionListener for the dragging, but I still need the MouseReleased Event because else I don't know when or on which slot the item is being released.

Im aware MouseClicked will only be called if the mouse hasn't moved from the point it was pressed when releasing it. But if it HAS actually moved MousePressed/MouseReleased should be called, right? I tried deleting all the code from the MousePressed event and leaving the drop on MouseReleased but it still doesn't drop it, although MouseClicked AND MouseReleased should both drop the item now.

Comment: OK - I think i fixed the problem. Copied the content of MouseClicked to MousePressed and kept a boolean to verify if i just dropped the item (to not pick it up again instantly) - It might be not the cleanest way of doing it but it seems to work right now. Thanks for the advice!